# input content in FF & Opera

Tags: firefox, user-input

i got a "register user to website" form on my site.
It looks fine in all browsers except Opera and FF..
i tryed to show pics through html so you can see what I mean, but i cant without 10 posts, and i can only post one link, so..

here is the one pic and the explanation ->
http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/4903/45825110.jpg

notice the vertical spacing between the input boxes...

how do I make it look the same in all the browsers?

thanks in advance for the anwsers..
Andrej

btw: i did't use any css resets on my page..

Comment: **TIP:** develop in Firefox first, then make fixes in other browsers. The odds are the only browser requiring fixing will be IE.

Comment: We're probably going to need to see some code to help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [tried it out in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh3DH/1/) and it seems to work fine.

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />

        <input id='kbr' />
        <label id='kbr_label' for='kbr'>Kbr:</label>

        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
        <input />
    </fieldset>
</form>​
```

**CSS**:

```
    fieldset {
        border: 1px dotted silver;
        padding: 1em;
        width: 10em;
    }

    input {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #kbr {
        width: 50%;
    }

    #kbr_label {
        float: right;
    }
```

**EDIT**:

[Version 2 in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh3DH/2/) gets rid of the last input boxes bottom margin.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough without seeing some code, but simple margin / padding issue like that across different browsers can often be remedied by using a browser reset in your css.

Here's an example, although if you do a google search you'll see that there are many others.

http://www.siolon.com/blog/browser-reset-css/

Answer (score 0):

First, try using a [strict doctype](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/doctypes) because it reduces cross-browser problems to almost none. At its most simplest you can put `<!doctype html>` as the very first thing on your page, before `<html>`.

Posting the HTML/CSS code would have been useful but it looks like you need to add a margin to the inputs. At its most basic adding `margin: 2px 0` to your styles for those input should work a treat.